# how to have multiple date formats on amCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

hi I have AmCharts JavaScript serial chart with multiple lines. 
The data is for months and also for years. I have created a chart of what I want in the image below. However, trying to achieve the same in AmCharts, I could NOT figure out how to have multiple date formats on the category axis. See the Blue and Red boxes in the image.

[image]

If i shift to dateformat "YYYY", all the monthly data from a year gets charted against one year. see the red box below

[image: Desired Output]

If I shift to dateformat "MMM", I see unnecessary blank months. see red box below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) in `categoryAxis` to specify granularity of your data. So if you have yearly data, you need to set it to "YYYY":

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true,
  "minPeriod": "YYYY"
}
```

This way you don't even have to set `dateFormats`, because the default format for he yearly data is already YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

```
"parseDates": false
```

this worked for me....